# PHP oci_fetch_array duplicates results list. from cities list

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I am using PHP `oci_fetch_array` to return a list of cities with its id

The loop duplicates 5 times the records from a query but running the same query into sql console it returns just one record for every city, as expected.

How can i fix this loop avoiding the return of duplicated cities ? i even try array_unique but it returns just one record and not the list of unique cities.

```
 while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
            echo "<br>".$row['cityid']." ".$row['cityname'];
    }
```

The entire code is this :

```
<?php
    $stateid = $_REQUEST['stateid'];
    $sql = "SELECT  cityid, cityname FROM cities WHERE cityState = {$stateid} ORDER BY cityname";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    oci_execute($stid);
    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
            echo "<br>".$row['cityid']." ".$row['cityname'];
    }
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Just for testing purposes can you please try `$sql = "SELECT 'count=' as cityid, count(*) as cityname FROM cities WHERE cityState = {$stateid} ORDER BY cityname";` and confirm that count really returns 1/5 of the records shown by the while loop?

Comment: Could not make the sugested query to run ! but in the sql plus the original query return the expected records with no duplicated cities.

Comment: i add a distinct and it solves the problem, but can not see why would it be need seems the loop duplicates the values.

Comment: Since it's the case here on Stackoverflow on at least a daily basis my first guess is: your script is using another database than you're using in the sql console. And if it follows the trope you will deny that, confirming that you've check again and again, only to admit an hour and 20+ comments later that it was indeed another database. But of course it's not always going that way - statistics just says "it's likely" ;-). The query above was just a first try to test that.

Comment: you are right they are diferent databases, they are supose to have the same data maybe into an unsync state. i just could not see this before .

Comment: Welcome to the club. Happens to all of us ;-)

Comment: Yes !!! even if you thought it would never happens :-) thank´s for helping to figure it out.